# Regular expression for a fake programming language

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I have an assignment to create a lexical analyzer that that translates the language into a series of tokens. I'm using java.util.regex to go through a string finding the different tokens and i put them into an array that i will go through and use that to assign them their respective tokens. Here is part of my program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        String[] symbols = {"+","-","*","/","<","<=",">",">=","==","!=","=",";",",",".","(",")","[","]","{","}","/*","*/","//"};
        String[] input;
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("src\\testCode.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        String ret = "";
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(s);
        }

        ret = sb.toString();

        input = regexChecker("regex goes here",ret);

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(input[i]);

        }
        System.out.println(input.length);
        in.close();       
    }  

public static String[] regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check){
         List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);
        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check);

        while(regexMatcher.find()){
            //regexInput = new String[regexMatcher.group().length()];
            allMatches.add(regexMatcher.group());
        }
        String[] regexInput = allMatches.toArray(new String[allMatches.size()]);

        return regexInput;
    }
```

My questions is: is there one regular expressions that can separate this language?Or am i going about my assignment all wrong by trying to use only one regex? Some of the lexical conventions are: identifiers start with an uppercase of lowercase letter or underscore followed by any word character. Comment lines and blocks are allowed. numbers are unsigned integers or real numbers in decimal notation. and there are keywords like int, double, if, etc. and special symbols like *,/,+ etc.

I can make regular expressions for each individual convention but im not sure how to combine them to form just 1,as my program requires.

Also i am using `(?://.*)|(/\\*(?:.|[\\n\\r])*?\\*/)` as my regular expressions for comments but it seems to not work for comment lines, just comment blocks. could the way read the file into a one line string be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend downloading [TinyPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28294/a-Tiny-Parser-Generator-v1-2). It is a Tiny Parser Generator, and supports a language similar to EBNF (Extended Backus-Naur Form) for grammars. It is for C#/VB, but the basic grammar definition should teach you a lot about parsers. If you understand C# or VB, you can examine the generated parser for some ideas on creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [`java.util.StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) but in many cases this is not flexible enough.

Of course you could write your own tokenizer. This is not as hard as it sounds, once you have done it yourself. Some people will tell you that you should use a tool / library instead, but I most of those who say this do it because they learned it like this at school, and don't have actual real-world experience in writing / maintaining tokenizers and parsers. There are quite many open source hand written tokenizers and parsers, for example [JSON/JSOP Tokenizer](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/oak/trunk/oak-mk/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/mk/json/JsopTokenizer.java), [JCR XPath Parser](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/oak/trunk/oak-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/query/XPathToSQL2Converter.java), [JCR SQL-2 Parser](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/oak/trunk/oak-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/query/SQL2Parser.java).